# Test task for c# vacancy, but i learned java)

Tags: c#

So, near 6 months I learning Java. But now I'm got a good job vacancy on c#, .net. I'm very interested in this job. They know about that I'm learned java, so they gave me a test task. And I ask about help from one of the most powerful community in the world. Can somebody explain me what technology I must use for each concrete part, and maybe give me GitHub example for study, or explain mechanism of dialog between technology. Or make some analogy from java

I need to make database with tables, and web service for it, and HTML page for view. At first page will load all records from database, but second it will load only fresh records. And in this web form gone be some buttons for queries to database.
Technical requirements:

- no asp.net web forms, it should be HTML
- table should be made on tag  and with CSS styles
- logic for working with table, should be on javascript
- calling web service on js too
- web service can be asmx, rest, WCF
- queries from buttons can be made by js or on web service by SQL or LINQ

Comment: This is way too broad for stackoverflow. You're asking us how to build a whole application. These are the kinds of things you can learn in tutorials. To be on-topic here, your question needs to be a lot more specific and focused on a single issue

Comment: But very generally, it sounds like asp.net core web API with a html/js frontend (maybe using some frontend framework if you want), and then you need a database for the backend - again, doesn't seem to matter which one

Comment: Overall I would say to build a new Asp.Net Core web app and JS or typescript for the frontend. I don't think anybody will give you a full answer here, SO is about providing specific questions, GitHub is full of examples about these kind of sample apps.

Comment: I can't use MVC templates. May be somebody can give me link to example on git hub, please. Because, it's hard to choose the right one

Comment: We don't do recommendations of off-site resources, sorry. It's specifically listed as an off-topic subject in the help area. Anyway you don't need to use MVC templates, that's why I suggested to use web API instead. Microsoft have some official tutorials so chances are that's where you should start as a beginner

Comment: P.s. the answer you accepted says to use MVC templates. If you can't use those, why did you mark it accepted??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target technologies should be using the net core technologies.

- You can use html with net core MVC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0

> The ASP.NET Core MVC framework is a lightweight, open source, highly testable presentation framework optimized for use with ASP.NET Core.
>
> ASP.NET Core MVC provides a patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that enables a clean separation of concerns. It gives you full control over markup, supports TDD-friendly development and uses the latest web standards.

This framework can also supply rest api connectivity that can be called from javascript.

You can also integrate with a framework like angular: https://medium.com/asp-net-and-angular/how-to-create-an-asp-net-mvc-5-project-with-angular-6-in-visual-studio-part-1-8b116e19a335

> The ASP.NET Core MVC framework is a lightweight, open source, highly testable presentation framework optimized for use with ASP.NET Core.
>
> ASP.NET Core MVC provides a patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that enables a clean separation of concerns. It gives you full control over markup, supports TDD-friendly development and uses the latest web standards.

For database connectivity, you can use entity framework core, for simple crud applications.

Dapper is also a good idea if you want to write your own queries.